# How to make a bootable usb by dd cloning another bootable usb using debian 10?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, debian, sd-card

I used the following command:

**"**sudo dd if=/dev/sdX bs=16M of=/filepath/name**"**

I see from the article below that there is a slightly different command I may be able to use.

**"sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/path.to.backup.img bs=4M"** --- but with this one, the ".img" doesn't seem to fit since I am trying to clone a whole OS with files, etc on it.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-copy-clone-usb-stick-including-partitions/

The usb (which is really a media card reader with a micro-sd) has the debian OS on it and some other files and inputs (ie: libreoffice). The sd is only 34% full. When I dd'd the empty (41M) micro-sd, it filled up the entire device and ran out of space. The amount of bytes on the "empty - "of"" sd is 3x's greater than the "if" sd.

I am trying to clone one micro-sd with another micro-sd using an usb media card reader.

Do I need to use a different command to make it clone properly? I need to boot from the newly cloned OS just as I can boot from the "if" micro-sd OS.

Comment: Forget how much is in use on the source USB. The destination USB must have >= the source USB capacity ,  available on the destination USB.  So if your source USB is 64GB then regardless of what is in use on the source.. Your desination USB has to have >=64GB free on it.  The resulting file on the destination will be 64GB

Comment: Also given your lack of a clue, I should point out that sdX won't do anything iit has to be eg sda or sdb  or sda1 e.t.c. but you have to get it right or you could wipe the wrong thing.  It is very dangerous that you have no grasp of what dd does.  Some joke that dd stands for disk destroyer, and in your hands it may well be so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the ".img" doesn't seem to fit since I am trying to clone a whole OS with files, etc on it.

You were looking at instructions about storing a backup of the card on the computer. But putting an .img file on a card won't actually make it bootable – even if it would fit, it's just going to stay there as a backup file and won't do anything.

Instead, when you're trying to make a 1:1 clone directly to another card, the output is supposed to be *the card itself* – not an .img file. Note how the input specifies `/dev/sdX`, the "block device" file, which gives you byte-level access to the card's entire data (including the boot sector, partition table, filesystem metadata, and everything else).

So in order to "clone" a card, the output must be the same thing – you need to specify a `/dev/sdX` path corresponding to the whole destination card, and allow the cloning process to completely overwrite the existing filesystem structures.

---

---

---

The `bs=` (block size) parameter doesn't have any effect on what data actually gets copied; setting it to somewhere between 4 MB – 32 MB just increases performance by copying more data at a time. (dd's default block size is tiny, so if you don't set a `bs=` it'll spend too much time switching back and forth.)

Comment: at gravity: worked perfectly! do you know when you would use the following command: "sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/path.to.backup.img bs=4M" It appears that I am adding something to an image, since my destination is an image already. It seems odd because I thought the dd would overwrite anything present on the destination, not add something to it. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that it is adding something?

Comment: Well, since the 'of' is an image instead of an empty drive; it is also being called a "backup". I can see how the 'backup.img' is what is going to be added to the empty (or not empty) destination though. But it would seem that if an image is being added, that the destination to that image would be the "if" location. That command seems very similar to copying over a whole device that is not bootable: "sudo dd if=/dev/sdx bs=16M of=/filepath/filename". It seems the 'filename' is being omitted. Thanks.

Comment: ...I'm sorry but I'm unable to interpret most of what you just wrote.

Comment: at grawity:  I can see now that someone is making a backup image to the destination (of=/)  with "sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/path.to.backup.img bs=4M". I thnk the only difference b/w this command the one in the confusing comment I wrote, sorry, is that in this one here the person is leaving off the filename for the destination. QUESTION: Just from a yes/no....when I scrub an sd using, 'sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdx bs=8192", does it matter if the destination (of=/) has a partition or not? Will the scrub work just as well if there is a partition present when the scrub starts? Thanks.

Comment: Partitions are irrelevant when reading/writing the "sdx" device, as it corresponds to the entire card from beginning to end. When writing to /dev/sdx, the partition table is actually the first thing you overwrite/destroy, and then it goes on to overwrite all partitions and all unpartitioned space.

Comment: at grawity: sounds good, thank you.